# Is there a use for drafters in the development in the next releases of Ubuntu?

Tags: development

I am a current tech student at Earnest Pruett Center of Technology (EPCOT) for my second year and I would like to know if I can help in any way with my drafting and design skills to develop any physical aspect of ubuntu. I have been top of my class the last two years and the practice would be well appreciated if anyone knows anything that can be assisted by a 2nd year drafter. thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is always looking for people to help, thank you! Start here: [Ubuntu Community](http://www.ubuntu.com/community)